# performance of ConcurrentQueue vs Queue + lock

Tags: c#

I have to implement one-consumer one-producer standard algorithm. I can implement it using `Queue` and couple of `lock` statements easily. Or I can just use `ConcurrentQueue`. What is better?

If `Queue + lock` is used then I can optimize "multiple addition/retreival", because I can `lock` once and then `Add` many times.

What is faster in general case - `ConcurrentQueue` or `Queue + lock` and how much the difference is? Of course `ConcurrentQueue` is the most straigt forward way but I do not want to loose a lot of performance as I'm using this in HFT trading application.

Comment: First, the performance is related to the CPU number. Is difficult to evaluate the performance of multithreading application in some abstract mode.

Comment: What about measuring in your environment? I can give you numbers which prove anything you want on my machine.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From [C# in a Nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0043D2DN2):

> The concurrent stack, queue, and bag classes are implemented
>   internally with linked lists. This makes them less memory efficient
>   than the nonconcurrent `Stack` and `Queue` classes, but better for
>   concurrent access because linked lists are conductive to lock-free or
>   low-lock implementations.

In other words, it's hard to define a general case, not to mention predict what the difference in performance will be.

It depends on the size of the collection and the usage. Performance can be expected to be better given enough concurrent access, memory consumption will be worse.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, from [Microsoft documentation regarding ConcurrentQueue(T) vs. Queue(T)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/when-to-use-a-thread-safe-collection#concurrentqueuet-vs-queuet):

> In pure producer-consumer scenarios, where the processing time for
> each element is very small (a few instructions), then
> System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue can offer modest
> performance benefits over a System.Collections.Generic.Queue that
> has an external lock. In this scenario, ConcurrentQueue performs
> best when one dedicated thread is queuing and one dedicated thread is
> de-queuing. If you do not enforce this rule, then Queue might even
> perform slightly faster than ConcurrentQueue on computers that have
> multiple cores.
>
> When processing time is around 500 FLOPS (floating point operations)
> or more, then the two-thread rule does not apply to
> ConcurrentQueue, which then has very good scalability. Queue
> does not scale well in this scenario.
>
> In mixed producer-consumer scenarios, when the processing time is very
> small, a Queue that has an external lock scales better than
> ConcurrentQueue does. However, when processing time is around 500
> FLOPS or more, then the ConcurrentQueue scales better.